# NameError: uninitialized constant Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-7

On Rails 6 app I had Rails.application.credentials in cap deploy.rb file. Now, when I try to deploy the new app with Rails 7 I'm getting

```
# bin/bundle exec cap production deploy --trace

NameError: uninitialized constant Rails

set :repo_url, Rails.application.credentials.git[:repo_url]
               ^^^^^
config/deploy.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/agasanov/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.17.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `load'
/home/agasanov/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.17.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/agasanov/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.17.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:32:in `untrusted!'
/home/agasanov/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/delegate.rb:87:in `method_missing'
               ^^^^^
```

Is this because autoloading from initializers have been removed from Rails 7?

Here is my deploy.rb

```
lock "~> 3.17.1"

set :application, "my app"
set :repo_url, Rails.application.credentials.git[:repo_url]
set :deploy_to, "/home/myapp/#{fetch :application}"

append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

set :keep_releases, 5
```

Comment: Please post your deploy.rb so that we can have some more context

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how deploy.rb may help here, but I've added it

Comment: Yeh, nothing particularly informative there. What output do you get if you run Capistrano with the `--trace` option?

Comment: Updated with --trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is because autoloading works differently in Rails 7. You cannot autoload from the autoload paths, which are managed by the main autoloader. This applies to code in config/initializers as well as application or engines initializers.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-when-the-application-boots

Answer (score 0):

There's an [old issue here](https://github.com/sgruhier/capistrano-db-tasks/issues/80) that suggests that Capistrano might raise this error if your deployment sees the Rails constant anywhere at deploy time (in the case of that issue, in `config/database.yml`, but if what it says is true the same would apply to `deploy.rb`).

That doesn't explain why it might have changed from Rails 6 to 7 though. Was your deploy.rb referring to `Rails.application` before you migrated?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the issue (and many others) before I posted the question here. I'm pretty sure this is not related to my issue. I have two exactly same applications with same lines in database.yml, deploy.rb or whatever, one is on Rails 6 which works fine and another one on Rails 7 which doesn't. I also tried to remove `Rails.application...` from database.yml and still getting same error

Comment: @AkhmedGasanov ok, so clearly Rails 7 breaks something that works with Rails 6. If we can isolate _why_ Rails 7 breaks we can also figure out how to fix it. Just making sure: you mentioned you removed `Rails.application` from the `database.yml` as a test, have you also tested the Rails 7 version without `Rails.application` in the deploy.rb?

Comment: Yes, and it works. I use environment variable for this to not stop the project.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Capistrano for both Rails 6 & 7?

Comment: And what's the capistrano-rails version in each app?

Comment: new app: capistrano-rails (1.6.2), capistrano (3.17.1). old app: capistrano-rails (1.6.1), capistrano (3.14.1). I don't see any changes in caps versions that may affect it((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251725/discussion-between-iftheshoefritz-and-akhmed-gasanov).